# trying to get a sample petstore using spring mybatis project working in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have downloaded the sample from http://mybatis.github.io/spring/sample.html.

1)I then open the pom.xml and imported it into intellij

2)I added a spring MVC facet

3) i added a web facet

4) i am using intellij 12.1.6

Once done, the autowiring is failing. I am trying to learn this new framework

All the service autowires have an error similar to::
        Could not autowire. No beans of 'LineItemMapper' type found

```
 public class OrderService {
   @Autowired
 private ItemMapper itemMapper;
   @Autowired
 private OrderMapper orderMapper;
   @Autowired
 private SequenceMapper sequenceMapper;
   @Autowired
 private LineItemMapper lineItemMapper;
```

I am thinking it is something i have setup incorrectly in my project.

this is the provided applicationCOntext from the example

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
     xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc     
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx   
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop   
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

     <!-- in-memory database and a datasource -->
     <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:database/jpetstore-hsqldb-schema.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:database/jpetstore-hsqldb-dataload.sql"/>
     </jdbc:embedded-database>

     <!-- transaction manager, use JtaTransactionManager for global tx -->
     <bean id="transactionManager"     
         class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
     </bean>

<!-- enable component scanning (beware that this does not enable mapper scanning!) -->    
<context:component-scan base-package="org.mybatis.jpetstore.service" />

<!-- enable autowire -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- enable transaction demarcation with annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven />

<!-- define the SqlSessionFactory -->
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="org.mybatis.jpetstore.domain" />
</bean>

<!-- scan for mappers and let them be autowired -->
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="org.mybatis.jpetstore.persistence" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

this is a zip of  the project https://www.dropbox.com/s/lohr3udnm0oa2hn/mybatis-jpetstore-6.0.1-sources.zip

Hopefully someone can point me to what i am doing incorrectly
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to try using the latest version of IntelliJ, released earlier this week. It has improved support for spring.

The underlying problem is that you need to set up IntelliJ's spring facet and assign the application context groups.

Comment: thanks, not sure when i can upgrade to v13. when looking at my spring facets i have my spring-config.xml and applicationContext.xml configured.

Comment: Just upgraded to v13 and still having the same problem

Comment: Try going to project structure, find the module you're using and adding a spring facet. Then click the + button in the lower left corner of the facet panel (on the right). Select the context files associated with this module and hit ok.

Comment: not sure i am following. So on the left, under the project tab there is a Structure tab and when i select a line item it shows the associated item in the config xml.